# How do i authenticate my app to a external service at startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, authentication

I'm not sure how to describe the whole thing, but basically I have a service app that serves an API. But in the background, I want the application to automatically log in to an external API.

Currently I have the login information stored in a class as private variables. However, here all sensitive login information is in plain text. And I would like to avoid having this information unencrypted in the code.

Comment: If you are ussing NET Framework you should have this information stored in web.config, if NET Core or NET 6, in appsettings.json

Comment: But the appsettings.json is readable from the outside. This makes the whole thing insecure again and offers a possibility to display the password.  - Or am I wrong ?

Comment: No, it not redeable. At least if you don't share it explicity. I suggest you search this here in this site.